# WPF negative Margin working different than expected (in ItemsControl)

Tags: wpf, calendar, margin, itemscontrol

I'm trying to make a calendar view in WPF, because the basic `<Calendar />` control isn't flexible enough, as I need a day-view to display meetings for that day. So I thought to myself, that I could just use an `<ItemsControl>` control and place the various meetings by applying some vertical Margin.

Before actually coding it, I wanted to test my idea and hardcode a sample. This is the result:
[image: hardcoded sample result]

```
<ItemsControl>
  <Label Content="[1] 9:30 - 10:00" Background="Fuchsia" Height="60" Margin="0 0 100 0"/>
  <Label Content="[2] 9:45 - 10:45" Background="Aqua" Height="120" Margin="100 -30 0 0"/>
  <Label Content="[3] 10:15 - 10:30" Background="Bisque" Height="30" Margin="0 -60 100 0"/>
  <Label Content="[4] 10:30 - 10:45" Background="Coral" Height="30" Margin="0 0 100 0"/>
</ItemsControl>
```

The result turned out quite good, although there are two things that surprised me:

1. I would've assumed, that [4] would be placed directly below [3], since it has a margin-top of 0, but apparently this isn't based on the previous element, but rather the bottom most element.
2. It's not very easy to see: [3] is placed lower, than I had planned. Every minute is represented by 2 units, so when [3] starts 30 minutes before [2] ends, I would assume, that a margin-top of -60 would result in the correct placement. With this margin, the blank space between [3] and [4] should be big enough to perfectly fit [4] in there, but it isn't. Instead, applying a top-margin of -90 results in the wanted placement of [3].

[image]

```
<ItemsControl>
  <Label Content="[1] 9:30 - 10:00" Background="Fuchsia" Height="60" Margin="0 0 100 0"/>
  <Label Content="[2] 9:45 - 10:45" Background="Aqua" Height="120" Margin="100 -30 0 0"/>
  <Label Content="[3] 10:15 - 10:30" Background="Bisque" Height="30" Margin="0 -90 100 0"/>
  <Label Content="[4] 10:30 - 10:45" Background="Coral" Height="30" Margin="0 0 100 0"/>
</ItemsControl>
```

I have the feeling, that as soon as lower edge of the element (in this case [3]) is higher than the lower edge of the previous element (in this case [4]), a negative margin-top places it according to it's vertical center line instead of the top line. But I'm struggling to figure out an equation to come up with the correct negative margin.

Does somebody have an explanation and maybe a hint towards how to correctly calculate this?

Thanks in advance
Julius

Comment: I would be more inclined to have a control in every 15 minute slot and make a number of em together look like one continuous thing. Rather than have a control per appointment.
It is almost always a bad idea to use large margins to position controls.
You'd do better using a canvas as itemspanel if you want flexible positioning

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a shot. Do you have an answer to the question, though?